# C++ Variable Checking

Tags: c++

Let's say I want the user to input an integer but he enters a double or a character value, how do I check that the the user has input the correct type.

```
string line;
getline(cin, line);
// create stringstream object called lineStream for parsing:
stringstream lineStream(line); 
string rname;
double res;
int node1,node2;
lineStream >> rname >> res >> node1 >> node2;
```

How do I check for valid input type?

Comment: You can enable exceptions and catch them

Comment: I don't remember how I did this, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You check the stream is OK:

```
if (lineStream >> rname >> res >> node1 >> node2)
{
    // all reads worked.
}
```

You may want to check for garbage on the end.

```
if (lineStream >> rname >> res >> node1 >> node2)
{
    char x;
    if (lineStream >> x)
    {
         // If you can read one more character there is junk on the end.
         // This is probably an error. So in this situation you
         // need to do somethings to correct for this.
         exit(1);
    }

    // all reads worked.
    // AND there is no junk on the end of the line.
}
```

#### Comment expanded.

From the comments below:

> if i input an integer for rname, it still works. for exmaple:

```
string line; getline(cin, line);
stringstream lineStream(line); // created stringstream object called lineStream for parsing
string rname; 
if (lineStream >> rname) { cout << "works"; }
```

Lets assume there is some properties about `rname` that allow us to distinguish it from a number. For example: it must be a name. i.e. it must only contain alpha characters.

```
struct Name
{
    std::string   value;
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& s, Name& data)
    {
        // Read a word
        s >> data.value;

        // Check to make sure that value is only alpha()
        if (find_if(data.value.begin(), data.value.end(), [](char c){return !isalpha(c);}) != str.end())
        {
            // failure is set in the stream.
            s.setstate(std::ios::failbit);
        }
        // return the stream
        return s;
    }
};
```

Now you can read a name.

```
Name rname; 
if (lineStream >> rname) { cout << "works"; }
```

This will fail if you enter an integer for rname.

#### Stretch Answer

If you have multiple lines of the same information you want to read. Then it is worth wrapping it in a class and defining a input stream operator.

```
strcut Node
{
    Name   rname;
    double res;
    int    node1;
    int    node2;

    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& s, Node& data)
    {
        std::string line;
        std::getline(s, line);

        std::stringstream linestream(line);
        lineStream >> data.rname >> data.res >> data.node1 >> data.node2;

        if(!linestream)
        {
            // Read failed.
            s.setstate(std::ios::failbit);
        }
        return s;
    }
};
```

Now it becomes easy to read the lines in a loop:

```
Node n;
while(std::cin >> n)
{
    // We read another node successfully
}
```

Comment: if i input an integer for rname, it still works. for exmaple:                                            string line;
    getline(cin, line);
    stringstream lineStream(line); // created stringstream object called lineStream for parsing
    string rname;
    if (lineStream >> rname);
    {
        cout << "works";
    }:

Comment: I don't know if you can read that but when i run the program and input lets say.. 5, it will still print "works"

Comment: @Andy: Yes because an integer is just a set of characters and thus is a valid string. If you want to define `rname` as its own type that has some special properties you can define the input operator that validates it. Is there some requirements about `rname` that make it look different from an integer?

Comment: @Andy this is because integer 123 is also considered as string, if you are checking for strings.

Answer (score 0):

Since string 123 will also be considered as string, and not an integer, so the better way is to iterate the string to end, until we find any non-digit character. here's how you may do it:

```
bool is_number(const std::string& s)
{
    std::string::const_iterator it = s.begin();
    while (it != s.end() && std::isdigit(*it)) ++it;
    return !s.empty() && it == s.end();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read node1 and node2 into strings first, then validate with a regular expression.

```
#include <regex>
...
string node1_s, node2_s;
linestream >> rname >> node1_s >> node2_s
if (regex_match(node1_s, regex("[+-]?[0-9]+") {
    /* convert node1_s to int */
} else {
    /* node1_s not integer */
}
/* Do same for node2_s */
```